# Export large SQL Server table to Excel using vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to export a large SQL Server table (around 1 million rows) to Excel using vb.net.

I can't even store it in a datatable, I get a system out of memory exception.

What is the best way to export table in (xls, xlsx) format in less time?

Comment: Not sure with VB. I'm not even sure that excel could handle a million records without using powerquery.

Comment: Excel has a row limit of 1 million rows. You can make an excel file with more rows than that, but you can't use Excel or features like OLE (that depend on Excel libraries) to create or open it. Looks like you're right up at that limit, and any table at that size is also likely growing.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestions. I will try and keep the records below 1 million as I want to export them in excel file. But any ideas to do export records into excel?

Comment: 1) Use a recordset instead of a datatable, 2) use the SAX method of writing an excel file using OpenXML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783286/openxml-sax-method-for-exporting-100k-rows-to-excel-fast

Comment: @PaulAbbott Thanks... I will try it...

Comment: Have you looked at the bcp utility (or SqlBulkCopy Class.) Most likely you can create a CSV file that Excel can read. file will be considerable smaller that an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a QueryTables object in excel with an OLEDB or ODBC connection to your SQL server table.

You can also use the Epplus library from codeproject to create an excel package without excel being installed and LoadFromReader or LoadFromCollection (not datatable). ie: Below code does a 1 million rows of data (with 2 fields only) insertion - the code is in C# but easy to conver to VB.Net):

```
void Main()
{
  ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();

  var collection = Enumerable.Range(1,1000000)
                   .Select (e => new {Id=e, Name="Name#"+e});

   var wsEnum = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("FromAnonymous");

   //Load the collection starting from cell A1...
   wsEnum.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(collection, true, TableStyles.Medium9);
   //...and save

  var fi = new FileInfo(@"d:\temp\AnonymousCollection.xlsx");
  if (fi.Exists)
  {
      fi.Delete();
  }
  pck.SaveAs(fi);
}
```