# An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, openxml

I have to store around 315k rows of data with 15 columns per row in an excel and make it available for download. I am retrieving all the data and then storing it in a Data Table and then using the OpenXml to write it to a workbook and send the response. But I get a exception `System.OutOfMemoryException` exception due to the huge volume of data.

When I tried it by retrieving around 100k records the whole this worked fine without any error.

I have seen similar question here on SO but it was with a `FileStream` and hence the size of the `MemoryStream` was set dynamically like

```
 MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(fileStream.size())
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do this with `DataTable` too. I believe updating the excel sheet row by row would be a option but that would include a lot of code for checking the datatype and such.

Also, I faced a lot of issue with "File being corrupt" by working with that. Hence, I prefer a xlsx file.

```
protected void DownloadDetailTable_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string value = ddl_AuditEnvironment.SelectedValue;
            String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stagingConnection"].ConnectionString;    
            // DataTable that stores the result set to be written on an excel. 
            DataTable dataTableObj = GetAuditData.GetDetailsTable(value, connectionString);

            string attachment = "attachment; filename=Summary.xlsx";
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
            workbook.Worksheets.Add(dataTableObj, "Migrated Records");
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
                workbook.SaveAs(memory);
                memory.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                memory.Close();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I had to deal with OutOfMemoryException while processing large XL files (around 50 to 75, MB compressed) as well. The only way was to switch the code from DOM XML manipulation to the XML streaming, SAX like. Regards,

Comment: Going throught this http://stackoverflow.com/q/24783286/3575018 approach re iterates the need for using Sax like approach for huge data sets. But I haven't seen any examples of this workbook being made downloadable. Can this be achieved by saving this workbook as a memory stream and flushing it. Or is this where the out of memory issue occurs?

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi The solution was to use SAX as opposed to DOM mentioned in the answer linked to my earlier comment.